# Word count from a dictionary with multiple list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dataset as below dictionary

```
a = {123: [[a, b, c], [a, c, d]], 234: [[a, b, c], [a, c, d]]}
```

I want to count the number of words of each key as below

```
{123:[(a,2),(b,1),(c,2),(d,1)], 234: [(a,2),(b,1),(c,2),(d,1)]}
```

I have tried to do search for examples but not able to understand how to make it work for my dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

a = {

    123: [
        ["a", "b", "c"],
        ["a", "c", "d"]
    ],

    234: [
        ["a", "b", "c"],
        ["a", "c", "d"]
    ]

}

result = {key: list(Counter(chain(*value)).items()) for key, value in a.items()}
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{123: [('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 1)], 234: [('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 1)]}
>>>
```